# Большая каменная глыба - можно ли так писать?

Tags: грамотная-речь, стилистика, стилистическая-сочетаемость

Большая каменная глыба - верно ли стилистически такое употребление? Или глыба и так носит значение чего-то большого?

Answer (score 1):

Глыба, конечно, подразумевает нечто немаленькое, но глыбы всё же могут быть разными. Сочетание "большая глыба" никакого отторжения не вызывает и достаточно широко употребляется. Можно посмотреть в гугле:

[Большая глыба](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&source=hp&ei=5pRSXdatDoKRmwX90bnwCg&q=%22%D0%91%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%B0%22&oq=%22%D0%91%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%B0%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i7i30i19j0i19j0i7i30i19l2j0i7i5i30i19j0i30i19l2j0i5i30i19.1753.6699..7864...0.0..0.133.890.12j1......0....1j2..gws-wiz.......0i13i30i19j0i13i5i30i19j0i8i13i30i19.LeH88Rb0-ok&ved=0ahUKEwjWuJjE1f_jAhWCyKYKHf1oDq4Q4dUDCAU&uact=5) - 12600 результатов.

А какие ещё глыбы бывают? Гугл и на это может ответить:

[Небольшая глыба](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&ei=WpVSXcGbGaCCk74PuPC-gA8&q=%22%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%B0%22&oq=%22%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%B0%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i19j0i13i30i19l2j0i13i5i30i19j0i8i13i30i19l3.168454.169292..170428...0.0..0.60.117.2......0....1..gws-wiz.pZ8eNpGFebs&ved=0ahUKEwjBsMv71f_jAhUgwcQBHTi4D_AQ4dUDCAo&uact=5) - 1420 результатов

[Огромная глыба](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&ei=BZZSXYDZEqWLk74P0sqccA&q=%22%D0%9E%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%B0%22&oq=%22%D0%9E%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%B0%22&gs_l=psy-ab.12..0i7i30i19l4j0i7i5i30i19j0i30i19.39876.42504..50186...0.0..0.64.476.8......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i7i30j0i7i5i30j0i8i7i30.i2TJkFSeGjs&ved=0ahUKEwjA74nN1v_jAhWlxcQBHVIlBw4Q4dUDCAo) - 47700 результатов

[Гигантская глыба](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&ei=N5ZSXdiLN4WFmwXP15zYCw&q=%22%D0%93%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%B0%22&oq=%22%D0%93%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%B0%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i30.78378.80273..81052...0.0..0.71.587.10......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i7i30j0i7i5i30j0i13i30.sK7F-jAhbEo&ved=0ahUKEwiYg5rl1v_jAhWFwqYKHc8rB7sQ4dUDCAo&uact=5) - 6500 результатов

Так что, как видите, дифференциация глыб по размеру всё-таки есть.

Comment: Ещё поиском находится множество "глыб средних размеров" (среднего размера глыб). Проблема только с "крохотными глыбами" :)

Comment: @Alex_ander, но при этом есть "маленькая глыба", правда нашлось всего 359 ссылок.

Comment: У геологов есть даже термин "малая глыба" (диаметр от 1 до 2,5 м).

Answer (score 0):

Глыба - большой обломок твёрдого вещества. Это словарь. Тогда стилистически правильно: каменная глыба.

Но правильным будет использование со словом `очень`: очень большая каменная глыба. Просто лингвистический трюк, так как `большая` ≠ `очень большая`.